# Automatically load Vi into insert mode

Tags: insert-mode, invocation

I use Vi as my preferred (and, in fact, only) text editor on Linux Systems. I know how to change modes from normal to insert, and vice-versa.

Is it possible to have Vi automatically load into Insert Mode rather than Normal Mode?

I want this because I can only access my Linux over SSH, and my computer that I can use for SSH access is *so* slow, it takes *ages* to load command mode. (Also my Openwrt system is quite slow).

Comment: This saves you a single keystroke when you don't need to navigate your file (i.e. in empty files) since navigation is easier in command mode. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Earthliŋ - Because I can only access my Linux over SSH, and my computer that I can use for SSH access is _*so*_ slow, it takes _*ages*_ to load command mode. (Also my Openwrt system is quite slow).

Comment: Thanks. Why don't you add this info to the question body? This way the question makes much more sense (to me at least) and will be easier findable (e.g. by searching "vim command mode slow to load").

Comment: That tag is confusing me. If this question is about "original vi", why is a `vim` answer accepted?

Comment: @muru Agreed. Changing the question two days afterwards, even if it was originally misinterpreted, makes a mess. At this point, it would be better to change the question to Vim and ask another question for Original Vi. I've voted to close as "Unclear what you are asking", and I would be glad to retract it if reverted.

Comment: I've reverted the tag; this question can stay open, the OP can ask a new question .... IMHO that's the easier ... Also, I think the the OP uses `nvi`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the `+startinsert` option (or `+star` for short) to start Vim with insert mode.

```
vim +star myfile.txt
```

If you want this to happen by default when starting Vim, you can make an alias (in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` for example) as follows:

```
alias vim="vim +startinsert"
```

However, that works only when starting Vim. If you want Vim to be in Insert mode even when you open a file from within Vim, add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile * startinsert
```

Answer (score 16):

```
$ vim -y <file>
```

> -y        Easy mode.  Implied for |evim| and |eview|.  Starts with        'insertmode' set and behaves like a click-and-type editor.      This
>   sources the script $VIMRUNTIME/evim.vim.  Mappings are        set up to
>   work like most click-and-type editors, see        |evim-keys|.  The GUI is
>   started when available.       {not in Vi}

[source](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html)

Answer (score 5):

Although I think starting in insert mode is not the vim way, you can do this very easily. You should start vim with

```
vim -c startinsert 'file'
```

The -c flag passes in a command into vim. The `:startinsert` command changes to insert mode. As you can imagine, you could start vim with any number of commands if you so desired.

Comment: Does this only work with Vim, or does it work also on Vi (My Openwrt system only has Vi).